# Reducing DOM + HTML size in client-side using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, dom, beautifulsoup

I am working on using Playwright (a web scraping & testing library) to navigate webpages, but prior to using Playwright's actions, I want to minimize the DOM I get from webpages.

The reason I am doing this is because I am experimenting with something by sending it to the GPT-4 API, and I am trying to meet token limits of under 4,000 tokens. So the more minimized the HTML is, the better.

This is the code I am working with. It currently removes unnecessary tags, comments, attributes (except for the necessary ones), and whitespace. It generally is able to reduce DOM size by about 30-40% depending on the webpage provided.

```
def minimize_html(html_content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    # Remove unnecessary tags
    for tag in soup.find_all(['style', 'script', 'meta', 'link']):
        tag.decompose()

    # Remove comments
    for element in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
        element.extract()

    # Remove attributes except for form-related elements and href
    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
        if tag.name not in ['form', 'input', 'select', 'textarea', 'button', 'a']:
            tag.attrs = {}
        else:
            if tag.name == 'a':
                href = tag.attrs.get('href')
                tag.attrs = {'href': href} if href else {}

    # Minify HTML by removing whitespace
    clean_content = str(soup).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').strip()

    return clean_content
```

My question is, is there anything more I can remove? Some other ideas I have is to cut text that is greater than 200 characters to further reduce the DOM size on text-heavy webpages.

Alternatively, is there a better way to reduce DOM size client side?

Comment: What are you wanting to give the GPT-4 API to analyze?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean up the results or even just send text, [Trafilatura is your friend.](https://trafilatura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

After minimizing the HTML with your existing approach, you can use Trafilatura to extract the main content:

```
import trafilatura

def extract_text_from_html(clean_content):
    extracted_text = trafilatura.extract(clean_content)
    return extracted_text if extracted_text else clean_content
```

By using Trafilatura, you're focusing on extracting the main content of the page, which usually excludes navigation, footers, sidebars, and other non-essential parts of a webpage (using Mozilla's readability API). This can significantly reduce the size of the content you're working with, especially on text-heavy webpages.(or pages with a ton of divs)

You could additionally use an HTML minifier (like [htmlmin](https://pypi.org/project/htmlmin/)) to further minify the code response.

You can also remove empty elements:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(True):
    if not tag.text.strip():
        tag.decompose()
```

You could also cut down the length of a tags text/truncate for certain tags and not others:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(['p', 'div', 'span', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'etc']):
    if len(tag.text) > 200:
        tag.string = tag.text[:200]
```